# divide 2 columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How to divide 2 columns in DB2. For example I have the below query

```
select x.planned,y.unplanned,(x.planned /y.unplanned) average from 
 ((select count(1) planned from 
  (select 1 from table 
  --------
  union all
  select 1 from table
  --------)) x
  join
 (select count(1) unplanned from 
 (select 1 from table
  --------
  union all
  select 1 from table
  --------)) y
  on 1=1)
```

This query brings output as

```
PLANNED  UNPLANNED  AVERAGE
  25         6         4
```

The value in AVERAGE is incorrect it should display 4.16 instead of 4. I'm not sure what is the mistake.

Comment: Why is 4.16 correct...? It depends on the result data type and the rounding.

Comment: You can use something like: `CAST( float(x.planned)/float(y.unplanned) AS DECIMAL(9,2) ) as average`   to explicitly control the result precision and scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like: `CAST( float(x.planned)/float(y.unplanned) AS DECIMAL(9,2) ) as average` to explicitly control the result precision and scale

Answer (score 1):

`25 / 6` equals `4⅙` it does not equal `4.16` unless you are explicitly rounding down the result to two decimal places.

For the most flexibility and precision when using decimal numbers in Db2 you could consider using use `DECFLOAT`.  For example

```
$ db2 "values 25::decfloat/6"

1                                         
------------------------------------------
       4.166666666666666666666666666666667
```

When rounding DEFFLOAT values, Db2 uses the values of the CURRENT DECFLOAT ROUNDING MODE special register to determine the rounding mode. This defaults to  `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (and is the only values allowed in some Db2 configurations).

```
db2 "values ROUND(25::decfloat/6,2)"

1                                         
------------------------------------------
                                      4.17

  1 record(s) selected.
```

to truncate (i.e. round down) then you can use `DECIMAL` and `FLOAT`s as Mao suggested, or to avoid issues with binary floating points, just `DECIMAL`s

```
$ db2 "values DECIMAL(25::DECIMAL/6,7,2)"

1        
---------
     4.16

  1 record(s) selected.
```